# how to sort data from a custom class

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting

Ok so i made a car race script in java . It has two classes. The `Car` class and `TheRace` class.

The `Car` class just has stuff about the car like the distance the car has traveled, and in `TheRace`, I have two arrays for the drivers (`driverArray`) and sponsors (`sponsors`). I made a `Car` class array so each driver have different speeds and distance traveled.

Anyway, as you can see I made a `boolean` called `winner`,  and a `while` loop that will keep going until the `winner` is `true`. The drivers distance becomes more and more in a `while` loop until `myDistance` is equal to or greater than `100`.

In the code you can see that, `if(carList[i].myDistance() >= 100){ winner = true;}`, So then i display the Winner.

I have been trying to make it so it shows all the people who eventually cross the finish line `100` , and display them in the corrector order they finished. Like sorting an array or something. How i can show what place everyone got. How do i do this?

`TheRace` class,

```
package NASCAR;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class TheRace {
// variables 
public static  String[] driverArray = {"steave smith", "Cheese farlin","Bob Joe","Josh Svioda", "Andrew Kralovec", "Ricky Bobby","Ashey GirslCanDriveTo","Kelsey IAgree","Joe ThisIsAManSport","Jess TheHellItIs","Jesus Defualt","Jason seglad","Andrew Smith","Andrew Johnson","Andrew Kosevsky","Andrew Anderson","Andrew Andrew", "Kate Andrew","Blondey Gold","Golden Blonde","Im Twenty" };
public static String[] sponsors = {"CocaCola","Pepsi","CoorsLight","GOD"} ;
public int[] currentDistance = new int[20]; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Car[] carList = new Car[20] ; 
    Random rand = new Random();

     for(int i =0 ; i < carList.length;i++){
         carList[i] = new Car(driverArray[rand.nextInt(20)], sponsors[rand.nextInt(4)]) ;
     } //end for 

     int lapCounter = 0 ; 
     boolean winner = false;
     while(!winner){

        for(int i = 0; i < carList.length; i++){
            carList[i].changeDistance();
            if(lapCounter % 6 == 0){
                carList[i].speedChange();                   
            } // end if change speed 

            System.out.println(carList[i].trackProgress());
            if(carList[i].myDistance() >= 100){
                winner = true;
                System.out.println("_____ THE WINNER OF THE RACE IS:  "+carList[i].myName()+"  For team: "+carList[i].myTeam()); 
                break ; 
            }

        }// end for 
        lapCounter++;
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");

    } // end while 

    }// end main 

}
```

`Car` class,

```
package NASCAR;
import java.util.Random;
public class Car {
//variables
 private float totalOdMiles ;
 private float speedPerHour ;
 private String driverName ;
 private String sponsorName ;
 private Random rand = new Random();


public Car(String driverName, String sponsorName){
this.driverName = driverName ; 
this.sponsorName = sponsorName ;
this.totalOdMiles = 0; 
this.speedPerHour = rand.nextInt( 60); 
}

public String myName(){
this.driverName = driverName;
return driverName ;         
}
public String myTeam(){
this.sponsorName = sponsorName;
return sponsorName ;    
}

public float myDistance(){ //reprot distance 
return totalOdMiles; 
}

public void speedChange(){ //ChangeSpeed()
this.speedPerHour = rand.nextInt(60); 
}

public void changeDistance(){ //UpdateProgress()
float milesPerSecond = this.speedPerHour / 3600;
this.totalOdMiles+=milesPerSecond;    
}

public String trackProgress(){ //ToString()
return this.driverName +" driving  the "+ this.sponsorName+" car is going "+ this.totalOdMiles +"MPS "+this.totalOdMiles;
}


}
```

Comment: There is a *whole lot* of code there, with very little to drive to what you're trying to do. Please try to rephrase your question with the following: The expected input, the expected output, and the **smallest subset of your code needed** to describe the problem/give us the knowledge of your data-structure to produce a solution. Otherwise everything just seems like noise. For example, right now you haven't even specified how you want the arrays sorted, which is pretty much a foundation of the question.

Comment: So the question is how to sort an array of `Car` objects by the `totalOdMiles` field?  Or did I misunderstand?  If that is the question, then very similar questions have been asked _many_ times before.  You probably want to write a `Comparator` for the `Car` objects, then use the `sort` method of the `Arrays` class.

Comment: You have posted a bunch of code which has nothing to do with your actual question, please try to be as specific as you can.

Comment: Is this better for everyone?

Comment: @user3450126, please see my updated answer for both Java 8 and previous versions of Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hava a look at this custom Comparator,

put this code after your `while` loop,

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(carList), new Comparator<Car>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
                return Float.compare(o2.myDistance(), o1.myDistance());
            }
        });
```

to print the sorted names along with their rank,

```
        for (Car s : carList){
            System.out.println(s.myDistance() + " " + s.myName());
        }
```

**Output:**

```
THE WINNER OF THE RACE IS:  Andrew Johnson  For team: CocaCola
100.004135 Andrew Johnson
99.623375 Jesus Defualt
99.23477 Andrew Smith
99.20563 Andrew Andrew
98.94183 Jesus Defualt
98.87631 Blondey Gold
98.86331 Jesus Defualt
98.64405 steave smith
98.54269 Jason seglad
98.24685 Bob Joe
98.23995 Andrew Kosevsky
98.06155 Ricky Bobby
97.81364 Jess TheHellItIs
97.77215 Blondey Gold
97.72567 Ashey GirslCanDriveTo
97.57001 Ashey GirslCanDriveTo
97.54619 Cheese farlin
97.29426 Andrew Kralovec
96.68102 Andrew Kosevsky
96.018654 Ashey GirslCanDriveTo
```

to list the first 5 places, use this instead,

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    System.out.println(carList[i].myDistance() + " " + carList[i].myName() + ", -- Rank: " + (i+1));
}
```

This could be done more easily if you are using Java 8,

```
    Arrays.stream(carList)
            .sorted((a, b) -> Float.compare(b.myDistance(), a.myDistance()))
            .map(c -> c.myDistance() + " " + c.myName())
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

This will get you the ranks of all the drivers in descending order along with their respective speed.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should avoid the problem of having to sort two arrays simultaneously by adding the currentDistance field to the Car class. Then you can sort the carList using currentDistance.

For example, using java 8 you can get the first 3 places with:

```
Arrays.stream(carList)
    .sorted((c1, c2) -> c2.currentDistance - c1.currentDistance)
    .map(c -> c.getName())
    .limit(3);
```

Comment: I dont think this i what i was looking for. You see i have a for loop that will run the drivers array until one person wins, if the 15 driver wins it will then be like driver 15 wins, then display the 5 other players. If driver 19 wins, it will be like driver 19 wins then display the 1 other driver. So i kinda want a loop or function that will then display the correct order of when they finished. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

I propose an easy solution based on what I think you're asking.

Simply create a new array, carPlace[] (as an example) and add carList[i] to that array as soon as they finish. 
That way 1st place will be carPlace[0], 2nd place carPlace[1] etc.

Once all cars are placed, then you can break out of the while loop as before.

You may not want to have your loop break as soon as a winner is found though - as this method requires all cars being added to the array.

If this is not what you are asking please specify ...

Happy coding!

Comment: Well as soon as they finish is kinda the problem. You see  i have a for loop that will run the drivers array until one person wins, if the 15 driver wins it will then be like driver 15 wins, then display the 5 other players. If driver 19 wins, it will be like driver 19 wins then display the 1 other driver

Answer (score -1):

your car class could imlpement the Comparable interface :

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car>

@Override
public int compareTo(Car o) {
    return this.totalOdMiles < o.totalOdMiles ? 0 : 1;
}
```

and the you can sort your array at the end of your while:

```
Arrays.sort(carList);
```

this should somehow work i guess :)

Comment: "this should somehow work i guess" -- no it won't , and you don't answer if you are unsure if your solution would work or not.